# Get a float's reciprocal?

Tags: java, math

I know getting the reciprocal of an int would go something like this:

```
int foo = 5;
float recip = 1/foo;
```

but how would you go about getting the reciprocal of a float? Would it go the same way? Right now I have the user inputting the reciprocal, which is not optimal. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

For clarification here's some pseudo-code:

```
float input = 0.25;
int recip = (get reciprocal here);
System.out.println(recip); //should return 4
```

Thanks!

Comment: integers can't store decimal digits. you can cast, but then you lose data

Comment: `float recip = 1/(float)foo;`. Or `float recip = 1F/foo`.

Comment: `float recip= 1/foo` doesn't give you the reciprocal of an int, it gives you `0`; did you even try that ? And is it so far reaching to try `1/input` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That wasn't my original question, not what I was looking for and I recall saying "something like this" instead of saying "goes like this". Please read the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how would you go about converting a float to an int?

That depends on what you want to have happen to the fractional part.

If you want to chop it off, you can cast:

```
float floatValue = 2.7f;
int value = (int)floatValue;
System.out.println(value); // 2
```

If you want to round it, use the various rounding methods in the JDK's library, such as [`Math.round(float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-).

```
float floatValue = 2.7f;
int value = Math.round(floatValue);
System.out.println(value); // 3
```

---

Re your comment:

> I am looking more for a way to find the reciprocal of the value, not the rounded value. For example, if I had 0.25 as my value, then I would like to receive 4 for my output, etc.

If the reciprocal is one over the value, then:

```
float input = 0.25f;
int recip = (int)(1.0f / input);
System.out.println(recip); // 4
```

...which chops off any fractional part, or

```
float input = 0.25f;
int recip = Math.round(1.0f / input);
System.out.println(recip); // 4
```

...which rounds it. (And there are other rounding methods that give you control over half-up vs. half-down vs. half-even, vs. rounding toward zero rather than positive infinity, etc.)

---

Side note: There's almost never a good reason to use `float` as opposed to `double`. And note that decimal constants, e.g. `2.0`, are `double`s. If you want `float`s, put an `f` at the end: `2.0f`. But again: Use `double`. :-)

Comment: Then do 1.0 divided by it and then round as above.

Comment: @user2352923: :-) I've added to the end...

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm. Sorry for the misleading question.